# change extent in map from 0, 360, 0, 300 to -180, 180, -90, 90

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, extent

how can I change the extent of a netcdf file from `0, 360, 0, 300` to `-180, 180, -90, 90`

Would the solution be the same if the original extents are

`0, 320, 0, 384`

`0, 362, 0, 294`

`0, 720, 0, 576`

`0, 362, 0, 332`

`0, 360, 0, 256`

`0, 802, 0, 404`

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 300, 360, 108000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 360, 0, 300  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : -1.728468, 35.60058  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the extent of raster data with the `raster` package like this

```
extent(x) <- c(0,1,0,1)
```

or with the `terra` package like this

```
ext(x) <- c(0,1,0,1)
```

What you are showing looks like row and column numbers, not coordinates. So how do you get these extents in the first place? How do you read the ncdf files?

Generally, the easiest way would be

```
library(terra)
x <- rast("ncdffile.nc")
```

if longitude is between 0 and 360 instead of -180 and 180, you can then do

```
y <- rotate(x)
```

Comment: Hi there, I can't get terra to work and I am trying to do something similar with the raster package- change 20, 380, -65, 80 to -180, 180, -90, 90. When I try and do extent(Mean_temp) <- c(-180, 180, -90, 90) like above, it doest actually get the correct data when I am plotting it. Is it because it's an offset of 20 between the example above, and my data?